# I challenge you to generate the following sequence

Tags: code-golf, sequence, restricted-source

I challenge you to generate the following sequence till 100 terms through any programming language in shortest characters possible.
The sequence is like this :-

```
1 2 3 4 5 10 20 30 40 50 100 200 300 400 500 ........
```

The output needs to be like this (above) only, nothing extra.

Remember, You can use `+` and `-` **only** and for mathematical calculations **only** (`++` and `--` are also allowed) and no other mathematical function like `tan()`, `log()`, `pow()`, ......etc.

Also, You cannot use any character variables in your code.

Comment: "You can use `+` and `-` only for mathematical calculations" So is this a [restricted-source] challenge?

Comment: Eh, seems easier to just treat them as strings and concat '0' each loop.

Comment: @algorithmshark can there be [restricted-source] + [code-golf]?

Comment: @MukulKumar Yes, that's allowed.

Comment: Wait a minute, if we can't use characters or strings, how do we output the numbers separated with spaces? Can they be newline separated instead?

Comment: @Doorknob You can use ASCII numbers, or string constants like ``\n`` I restricted only character variables and not constants.

Comment: Is something like n=int(str(n)+'0') in Python legal? It has no character variables.

Comment: @isaacg `no character variables...` valid

Comment: “You can use `+` and `-` only for mathematical calculations” – Does this mean that I must not use `+` and `-` for something other than mathematical calculations or does this mean that I must not use any other mathematical operators than `+` and `-`?

Comment: Although it's easy to guess which sequence you mean here, you haven't actually defined it. Any sequence of 100 numbers starting with the 15 you specify will be correct. For example: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, ... probably isn't what you want.

Comment: The wording is causing confusion. Please clarify whether `+`,`-`,`++`,`--` can be used for string operations. Also please explicitly state whether multiplication/exponentiation is allowed. VTC till then.

Comment: It is a similar ambiguous question as http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/25938/challenge-to-generate-a-mathematical-sequence

Comment: @MukulKumar I'm curious what you were shooting for here. Did you mean you wanted only addition operators and no padding 0s at the end? IOW, would you have considered this 58-char perl solution to be correct? '$x=$i=1;for(1..20){print$x;print$x+=$i for 1..4;$i=$x+=$x}' Basically repeat { print(x); x += i; print(x); x += i; print(x); x += i; print(x); x += i; print(x); x += x; i = x }

Comment: BTW, the problem with the above in many languages is that you run out of 64 bit ints 4 numbers too soon.

Comment: 25 chars in Matlab/Octave: x=[1:5].'*10.^[0:19];x(:)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### GolfScript (21 chars)

If

> You can use + and - only for mathematical calculations

means what it says then:

```
[6,1>~{4$10*}95*]' '*
```

If it is intended to say

> The only mathematical operators you can use are + and -

then the multiplications can be replaced with string manipulation at the same character count:

```
[6,1>~{4$0`+}95*]' '*
```

Dissection:

```
[         # Start gathering values into an array
  6,1>~   # Dump the numbers 1 to 5 onto the stack
  {       # Beginning of loop body
    4$    # Copy the 5th item on the stack
```

Here the variants differ

```
    10*   # Multiply it by 10
```

or

```
    0`+   # Postpend '0'
```

And then merge again

```
  }95*    # Loop 95 times, so we end up with 100 items on the stack
]         # Gather those 100 items into an array
' '*      # Space-separate them
```

Comment: I don't know GolfScript but `4$10* # Copy the 5th number on the stack and multiply by 10` -- Only addition subtraction and (in|de)crements are allowed

Comment: @user80551, that's not clear to me, but it's easily worked around at the same character count.

Answer (score 4):

### Perl, 38 bytes

Disclaimer: The restrictions of the changed question are not too clear to me.

```perl
for$i(0..19){print$_.0 x$i.$"for 1..5}
```

The code uses variables with integer values except for `$"` which is used for the separation space. It can be easily replaced by `' '` (+1 byte).

Mathematical operations are not used, the code only contains string concatenations and the repetition operator.

The result are 100 numbers:

```
1 2 3 4 5 10 20 30 40 50 100 200 300 400 500 1000 2000 3000 4000 5000 10000 20000 30000 40000 50000 100000 200000 300000 400000 500000 1000000 2000000 3000000 4000000 5000000 10000000 20000000 30000000 40000000 50000000 100000000 200000000 300000000 400000000 500000000 1000000000 2000000000 3000000000 4000000000 5000000000 10000000000 20000000000 30000000000 40000000000 50000000000 100000000000 200000000000 300000000000 400000000000 500000000000 1000000000000 2000000000000 3000000000000 4000000000000 5000000000000 10000000000000 20000000000000 30000000000000 40000000000000 50000000000000 100000000000000 200000000000000 300000000000000 400000000000000 500000000000000 1000000000000000 2000000000000000 3000000000000000 4000000000000000 5000000000000000 10000000000000000 20000000000000000 30000000000000000 40000000000000000 50000000000000000 100000000000000000 200000000000000000 300000000000000000 400000000000000000 500000000000000000 1000000000000000000 2000000000000000000 3000000000000000000 4000000000000000000 5000000000000000000 10000000000000000000 20000000000000000000 30000000000000000000 40000000000000000000 50000000000000000000
```

**Ungolfed:**

```perl
for $i (0..19) { # 20 * 5 = 100 numbers
    for $_ (1..5) {
        print $_     # first digit
            . 0 x $i # zeros
            . $"     # separator (space)
    }
}
```

Comment: Not a bad solution. The shortest I could manage was 34: `print 1..5,!($,="0$,"||$")for a..t`

Answer (score 4):

### Python 60

```py
r=range
for i in r(20):
 for j in r(1,6):print str(j)+'0'*i,
```

---

Thanks to @ace for pointing out that this was way too long.

### Python 113

```py
from itertools import*
i=j=0
for x in cycle(range(1,6)):
 i+=1;print str(x)+'0'*j,
 if i%5==0:j+=1
 if i>99:break
```

Comment: It should be shorter if you use two loops instead of itertools

Comment: `for j in'12345'` lets you omit the `str()` command, which brings you down to 51 characters, if you remove the first line and spell out range

Comment: @MrLemon `j` will then become a character variable which is not allowed.

Comment: @user80551 I totally overlooked that part, you are correct.

Comment: Use list comprehension and this will reduce to 47 characters `[i*10**j for j in range(21)for i in range(1,6)]`

Comment: @Abhijit Can't use multiplication or exponentiation.

Answer (score 3):

## GolfScript, <s>30</s> 25 characters (<s>26</s> 23 newline separated)

```
;6,1>{.{10*}%}20*][]*' '*
```

Commented:

```
;         # pop the input string (empty)
6,1>      # generate [1 2 3 4 5]
{.{10*}%} # duplicate the array and multiply everything by 10
20*       # do this 20 times (5 * 20 = 100)
]         # wrap the whole stack in an array
[]*       # flatten
' '*      # join by space
```

<s>I really don't like the repetition at the end, but GS doesn't provide a `flat_map` or `flatten` of any sort.</s> Thanks @PeterTaylor for providing a way to flatten!

If we can separate by newlines instead of spaces, then **23 characters**:

```
;6,1>{.{10*}%}20*][]*n*
```

Comment: You should create a programming language called DoorknobScript.

Comment: To get an array of `1` to `5` it's better to do either `6,(;` or `6,1>`. GS does provide a couple of ways to do one-level `flatten`: `[]*` or `{~}%`. But to use either you'll need to remove the initial `''` from the stack (which is currently giving you output with a leading space) or avoid including it by using an explicit `[`.

Comment: `{.{10*}%} # duplicate the array and multiply everything by 10` Multiplying isn't allowed.

Comment: @user Where does it say that? Most of the other answers use multiplication too.

Comment: It says "Remember, You can use + and - only and for mathematical calculations only (++ and -- are also allowed)".   Doesn't "only" means ..... "only"?

Answer (score 3):

### APL (<s>17</s> 24)

```
,⍉10⊥¨(⍳5)∘.{⍺,1↓⍵/0}⍳20
```

Comment: Multiply and power are not allowed.

Comment: @user80551: ok I changed it

Answer (score 2):

## C, 93

```c
i;main(j,k){for(;++i;)for(j=0;++j<6;){for(putchar(48+j),k=0;++k<i;putchar(48));putchar(32);}}
```

// it draws nice patterns on the terminal...

Comment: [87 bytes](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z/TOjcxM08jSydbszotv0jDWls701oTxMqyNbXO0tW1LigtSc5ILNIwNtIEi2fbKsKETI11szSBOrJtMuHKTCw0Na1r//8HAA "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## Java,185

```java
class g {public static void main(String[] args){for(int x=0;x<20;x++){for(int i=1;i<6;i++){System.out.print(""+i); for(int j=0;j<x;j++){System.out.print("0");}System.out.print(" ");}}}}
```

Comment: You forgot a space between `int` and `j` so your code didn't compile. I edited your answer to fix that.

Comment: It's also an infinite loop rather than printing 100 terms.

Comment: Oh ok, sorry I'll edit it.

Comment: You can get it down to 169 by 1) renaming `args` 2) restructuring the loops and 3) declaring your `int`s up front : `class G{public static void main(String[]a){int x=0,i,j;for(;x<20;x++)for(i=0;i++<5;System.out.print(" ")){System.out.print(""+i);for(j=0;j++<x;System.out.print("0"));}}}`

Comment: Can't you remove the space just before the third `for`

Answer (score 2):

## Julia - 38

```
[print(i,"0"^j," ") for i=1:5,j=0:19];
```

#### Output:

```
1 2 3 4 5 10 20 30 40 50 100 200 300 400 500 1000 2000 3000 4000 5000 10000 20000 30000 40000 50000 100000 ...
```

Comment: -1 , multiplication and power are not allowed.

Comment: Now they are strings, so i think it doesnt break the rules

Comment: I just wrote the exact same solution before seeing yours.

Answer (score 2):

## PHP - 61

```
for($i=0;$i++<21;)for($j=0;$j++<5;)echo str_pad($j,$i,0).' ';
```